# Upgraded to Win10, WIFI stopped working (no internet connection)

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10-upgrade

I've just upgraded to Windows 10 on my portable with Windows 8.1.

After that my WIFI connection stopped working. It seems like none of my adapters get an IP-address. It works fine with a cable.

```
C:\Users\jgauffin>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Broadcom 4313GN 802.11b g n 1x1 Wi-Fi Adapter Virtual Switch):

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b5d4:ebd2:5e33:d519%15
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.213.25
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Broadcom 4313GN 802.11b g n 1x1 Wi-Fi Adapter Virtual Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d84b:c446:53e0:3171%9
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.49.113
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller Virtual Switch):

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{BC651D0A-9D50-47F4-998D-4C75680C02BA}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{2CE88CB0-0162-4372-96F3-E15F7359963A}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{FEDAD4C5-EA1E-4CBB-A918-7A9EC3492D01}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

I've made windows to forget it under the network settings and then connected again to see of that helped. It didn't.

I got a lot of virtual adapters, did they get screwed up during the upgrade? Would it help to remove those? If so, how?

Comment: Reinstall wifi adapter drivers? or you can try to format and do a clean installation of windows 10 your PC will remain activated.

Comment: Which channel are you using? My laptop stopped to connect after the upgrade to channel 13. http://superuser.com/questions/982401/dell-n7110-unable-to-connect-to-ap-after-win10-upgrade/982483#982483

Comment: Reinstall the wifi drivers and reboot helped. @Chris.C: Add an answer.