# Dell N7110 unable to connect to AP after WIN10 upgrade

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10

After upgrading my Dell N7110 from Win7 to Win10 it was not able to connect to the Access Point it used before. It still managed to connect to the router, but as it was much farther the speeds are horrible. I have the AP just because the router is too far.
The router and the AP are the same make and model, TP-LINK TL-WR841N. They use the same encription, same SSID, same password.

Unfortunately the Win7 got corrupted during the upgrade, so reverting to it is not an option.

I have removed wifi driver, connected the laptop to the AP with a cable, and refreshed the driver, but this did not help.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

### Do not use channel 13

The one thing that was different between the router and the AP was the channel. It seems Win10 on the Dell N7110 does not like that.
Strange, considering I am in Hungary, where it is legal, with a Hungarian Windows and it was working fine before the upgrade.